# Automatically add facebook like button to dynamic products

Tags: dynamic, facebook-like

We will be launching a daily deal site and want to add a facebook like button to each new deal that we launch. Each new deal will be on a different subdomain.

How can we add the like button to each new page automatically.

Thanks

Ali

Answer (score 1):

If the each of pages have unique URL you can simply use generic XFBML code for like button without `href` attribute, since it defaults to current page.

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

hence placed on pages http://deal-1.boiling-water.org/ and http://deal-2.boiling-water.org/ will result in two different like buttons with separate counts (Take into account that graph edges created by like button identified by URL, so http://deal-3.boiling-water.org and http://deal-3.boiling-water.org/some/subpage are two different objects as well).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need to update like button code on each sub domain.Here is the code you may use

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%=YourPageUrl %>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:30px; margin-top:5px"></iframe>
```